# can't connect to azure devops using ssh even after uploading my public key to azure

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, devops

I have the ssh keys stored under ./ssh director, uploaded my public ssh id_rsa.pub in azure devops and now when i try to do git clone ssh it says:

> The Git repository with name or identifier xxx does not exist or
>   you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

What else one should be doing except create a pair of ssh keys upload public key to azure in the project and try to clone it?

Also could it be possible that same ssh key is used under another project in azure?

thanx

Comment: Where did you perform `git clone`? pipeline, local machine or other place? Please describe the execution environment in detail.

Answer (score 0):

According to this error, I give the following troubleshooting.

1. Please make sure you have sufficient permissions on the repository. You can check by Project Settings->Repositories->Security

[image]

2. Please check if your access level is `Stakeholder` under Organization Settings->User. The stakeholder have no permission to clone a repo.

In addition , you can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page) and here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985167/git-ssh-public-key-authentication-failed-git-azure-devops) with some solutions you can refer to .

As a workaround , you can try to clone with HTTPS url and authenticate access with [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). This is the most effortless solution at hand. Simply switch to cloning from the HTTPS path for your Git repository.