# Git for windows - “The authenticity of the host can’t be established” while running terraform init

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh, terraform

[image: Getting this error message]

So I am trying to run a terraform init from my local machine against code hosted in azure devops

I am getting this prompt and not sure how to proceed. I’ve tried y, yes, leaving it blank but it errors out and doesn’t download the modules

I recreated the ssh keys on my local machine and performed:

```
Ssh-key scan -H -t rsa.ssh.dev.azure.com > $env:userprofile/.ssh/known_hosts

Ssh-key scan -H -t vs-visualstudio.com > $env:userprofile/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Still getting the prompt and still getting a

```
Could not download module “**********” source code from git@vs-ssh.visualstudiocode.com/v3/<organization_name>/<project>/<repo>
…
Public key authentication failed
Fatal: could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Tried in visual studio and Git bash terminal.

Any idea on what I am supposed to enter in that box and how to proceed?

Comment: `Ssh-keys can` does not seem right, did you mean `ssh-keyscan`? If you did use `Ssh-keys can`, this probably did not work, which would leave you with the same problem. However, the `public key authentication failed` message suggests that you've moved on to a different problem, which is that you don't have the right keys set up.

Comment: @torek Typo in the post, just amended. Would the issue be that I need specifically configure ssh keys within visual studio code?

Comment: I don't know if VS has any special ssh items. Git itself just *runs* ssh, which is why Git-for-Windows comes with an ssh implementation: some Windows systems don't have any ssh to run. This in turn leads to Windows problems where you configure ssh on Windows (configuring ssh installation #1) and then you run `git clone` with an ssh URL and Git runs ... ssh installation #2, which uses completely different configuration files, and hence isn't configured, even though you configured ssh.

Comment: The usual solution to *that* problem is to remove the extra ssh and/or make sure Git uses the system-provided ssh, as long as the system-provided ssh actually works with Git. That way you don't have two separate ssh subsystems with separate configurations.

Answer (score 1):

> Still getting the prompt and still getting a

Regarding the Public key authentication failed, check "[Git SSH public key authentication failed with git on Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73637949/6309)"

You would still need to define a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file in order to reference the right private key for `git@ssh.dev.azure.com` and `git@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com`

Try also (as noted in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#q-after-running-git-clone-i-get-the-following-error-what-should-i-do)):

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa ssh.dev.azure.com >> $env:userprofile/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -t rsa vs-ssh.visualstudio.com >> $env:userprofile/.ssh/known_hosts
```

That differs from the `Ssh-key scan -H -t vs-visualstudio.com` from your question.