# Cloning project from Cpanel git, showing this error "ssh remote host identification has changed"

Tags: git, rsa, cpanel

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but there's a difference here:

Trying to clone project from cpanel shared hosing server:

If tried with this command `sudo git clone ssh://mlbrpkxs@mlbranch.com:21098/home/mlbrpkxs/unified.mlbranch.com`
it show the following error.

```
Cloning into 'unified.mlbranch.com'...
Unable to negotiate with 63.250.38.32 port 21098: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then if found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208495/unable-to-negotiate-with-xx-xxx-xx-xx-no-matching-host-key-type-found-their-of) and try to clone with this command.

`sudo GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss" git clone ssh://mlbrpkxs@mlbranch.com:21098/home/mlbrpkxs/unified.mlbranch.com`

```
 Cloning into 'unified.mlbranch.com'...
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
 Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
 It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
 The fingerprint for the DSA key sent by the remote host is
 SHA256:hSIV2UEWbLuZQu2gkNaYNYxfmOd59VGlaNwXI85P+fA.
 Please contact your system administrator.
 Add correct host key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
 Offending RSA key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
 Host key for \[mlbranch.com\]:21098 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
 Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The most relevant question I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233777/git-error-unable-to-negotiate-with-xx-xx-xxx-xxx-no-matching-host-key-type-fo), which is closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840012/ssh-remote-host-identification-has-changed) which itself is closed as off-topic. But they're not the same anyway. Another related question is asked [here](https://osdir.com/).

In most cases, as we know, you can fix the problem by replacing the server key, for example by running:

```
ssh-keygen -R <host>
```

In my case:

```
ssh-keygen -R "[mlbranch.com]:21098"
```

But neither this solution, nor removing the offending key from the file `~/.ssh/known_hosts` did solve my problem.

I have clean all of my known_hosts recommend by an answer by stackOver flow. Now I am completely stucked and unable to find any solution how can I resolve this issue.

Please note that I am using Mac book and my code is on a shared hosting that is using the Cpanel. On my other Mac's I can get the clone.

Comment: You run `sudo git clone` as root (which you shouldn't do in the 1st place) hence all your other commands must be run as root (with `sudo`): `sudo ssh-keygen -R <host>`, etc. But better do not use `sudo` — it's not required for GIt operations. `~` with `sudo` mens `/root/` directory, not your home.

Comment: Its not run the command if I did't enter `sudo`

Comment: That should be fixed and then you can avoid `sudo`.

Comment: Related re: removing old host keys ["Warning: Remote Host Identification Has Changed" — Did GitHub change their RSA key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75830783) - some answers there mention removing based on IP address as well as hostname, since ssh may add records for those as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check first where is your private key.

If it is in `/home/aUser/.ssh`, then `sudo xxx` will ignore it completely.
You would need `sudo ssh -i /home/aUser/.ssh/myPrivateKey mlbrpkxs@mlbranch.com:21098` if you *have to* use `root`.

With Git:

`sudo "GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -i /home/aUser/.ssh/myPrivateKey" git clone ssh://mlbrpkxs@mlbranch.com:21098/home/mlbrpkxs/unified.mlbranch.com`

The best practice, however, is to avoid `sudo` except for system admin commands.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Once I run `
 sudo ssh -i /home/aUser/.ssh/myPrivateKey... ` then its showing me this error, `
not accessible: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Naqvi Did you replace "`myPrivateKey`" by your actual private key? And remove last three dots (`...`), just for testing the SSH access?

Comment: Yes I have replace it with my private key, and I use this command to find my private key `/Users/naqvi/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: @Naqvi I have edited the answer to use the parameters from the question. Why use `sudo` though in your case?

Comment: if I did't enter the sudo keyword its shows me this error ` Permission denied`

Comment: @VonC its some me the same error of permission if I use it without sudo.

Comment: @Naqvi Then change the permission of the current folder you are in, in order for your user to have the right to write in it.

Comment: @QaziAmmar Perfect, no need for sudo then. You get the "no matching host key type found"?

Comment: if I did't enter sudo then its shows this complete error, `fatal: could not create work tree dir 'mywebsites.com': Permission denied `

Comment: @Naqvi Hence the sudo chown, to make sure your current folder is owner by your current user.

Answer (score 1):

Github just have updated the RSA SSH host key recently!

> At approximately 05:00 UTC on March 24, out of an abundance of caution, we replaced our RSA SSH host key used to secure Git operations for GitHub.com.

To fix that, just add the new RSA SSH host key to `.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Remove the old key by running this command:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

And add this to file `.ssh/known_hosts`

```
echo "github.com ssh-rsa <OMITTED KEY>" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

If you prefer do it manually

```
github.com ssh-ed25519 <OMITTED KEY>
github.com ssh-rsa <OMITTED KEY>
```

Or only this, if others not needed.

```
github.com ssh-rsa <OMITTED KEY>
```

Keys from source here:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

Comment: Link to github announcement: https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

Comment: PSA to anyone reading: don't copy/paste any of the keys mentioned in the answer - go to the official source for it

Comment: For GitHub specifically, see ["Warning: Remote Host Identification Has Changed" — Did GitHub change their RSA key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75830783).  (A moderator deleted a cross-posted copy of this answer there; they should have deleted this copy of it, since it's about the specific case of github, not this question.  And this answer doesn't address CPanel.)  Also, don't tell people to copy/paste keys from Stack Overflow or other sources that don't have a chain of trust leading back to the original owners.  It's not good security hygiene.

Comment: I understand your concerns, and I added the ORIGINAL SOURCE AS PART OF THE ANSWER, as you can see in the original answer. I gonna edit answer, just to omit them, to avoid misunderstanding