# Github SSH Host Verification Failed when trying to run git command

Tags: git, github

When trying to run any git command (fetch, pull, push, etc) against Github, a Host Verification Failed message is displayed similar to:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Host key for github.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Warning: Remote Host Identification Has Changed" — Did GitHub change their RSA key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75830783/warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed-did-github-change-their-rsa) (I understand the temptation to self-answer a question that will/is as popular as this topic, but please search first if it was already done).

Comment: Thanks for the link - I had searched and didn't find the question prior to posting.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub had a issue with their rsa ssh host token

See article below to fix this

https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/