# Github Actions Can't Clone Submodule Over SSH in Same Organization

Tags: git, github, ssh, github-actions

I have two repositories in the same organization: A and B.

Repository B is a submodule in repository A.

**Both** repository A and B are part of the same organization.

**Both** repository A and B have the setting "*Accessible from repositories in the 'organization-name' organization*" checked/enabled.

In my github actions workflow for repository A, I have the following line:

```
- run: git submodule update --init --recursive
```

But I get the following error when trying to clone repository B:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Am I missing a step?  Do I have to set up SSH keys in my workflow yml file?  If so, why? Both repositories should have access to each other given the setting I have enabled.

Comment: Potentially related: ["Warning: Remote Host Identification Has Changed" — Did GitHub change their RSA key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75830783/11082165)